# How to insert the image in layout background?

Tags: android

Insert the image in login layout background in android.

Comment: Just set this `android:background="drawable/yourimage"` into your parent layout of `login.xml`

Comment: android:background="@drawable/yourback"

Comment: Why it's not real question? It's short but clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/your_image"
```

In code (`setBackgroundDrawable` is deprecated since API 16, but still helpful)

```
.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d);
//or
.setBackgroundResource(int resId);
```

Since API 16:

```
.setBackground(Drawable d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this -

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/loginLayout" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/background">
    ....
    ....
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:orientation="vertical" will it work for RelativeLay??

Comment: @PadmaKumar Enough? See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ad_screenfull"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```